# How to remove newline in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, newline, mips

So I am busy writing a MIPS program that will take an input string, and then print all possible UNIQUE permutations of that string.  (AKA if the word is LoOp, LoOp and LOop are the same).

In order to do this, I know I need to NOT have a newline character on the end of my input string, but I don't know to make sure it's not added.  Here is what I have so far:

```
.data


newLine:
    .asciiz "\n"
promptUser:
    .asciiz "Enter a 20 letter or less word:\n"
word:
    .space 21

.text

main:

    la $a0, promptUser
    li $v0, 4       # Ask User for Input
    syscall

    la $a0, word
    li $a1,21       # Max number of characters 20
    li $v0,8
    syscall         # Prompting User

    la $a0,newLine      # Newline   
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    la $a0, word        # Printing Word
    li $v0, 4
    syscall
```

The only time a '\n' isn't included is when the number of letters entered is exactly 20.  Any suggestions??

FIX:

This works:

```
    li $s0,0        # Set index to 0
remove:
    lb $a3,word($s0)    # Load character at index
    addi $s0,$s0,1      # Increment index
    bnez $a3,remove     # Loop until the end of string is reached
    beq $a1,$s0,skip    # Do not remove \n when string = maxlength
    subiu $s0,$s0,2     # If above not true, Backtrack index to '\n'
    sb $0, word($s0)    # Add the terminating character in its place
skip:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string upon returning from syscall 8 to remove the character:

```
# your code to prompt the user        

    addu  $a2, $zero, $zero     # i = 0
loop:
    lbu $a3, word($a2)          # word[i]
    addiu $a2, $a2, 1
    bnez $a3, loop       # Search the NUL char code

    beq $a1, $a2, skip   # Check whether the buffer was fully loaded
                         # Otherwise 'remove' the last character
    sb $0, word-2($a2)   # and put a terminating NUL instead
skip:

# your code continues here
```

Also note that you didn't reserve enough space for the word. You should reserve 21 bytes with

```
word: .space(21)
```

Comment: Did not quite work.  What is the purpose of the xor $a2,$a2,$a2?

Comment: @user1739675: It sets register $a2 to zero. Have you put the snippet between the syscall that prompts the word and the line that says `la $a0,newLine` ?. And also, do you have delayed branching activated ? If thats the case you can add a `nop` after the `bnez $a3, loop`

Comment: I can't post my own answers, lawl.  But using your code as a guide I was able to achieve the intended result with the following code.

Comment: @user1739675: Great. Note that the code you posted is basically the same as mine, so it should have worked without modification ;)

Comment: Don't xor-zero in MIPS, only x86, especially if you're going to read from a register other than `$zero`.  In MIPS it's required to have a dependency on the input for memory dependency-ordering (the same thing `std::memory_order_consume` is supposed to expose.)

Comment: Also, MIPS addressing modes have a 16-bit immediate; you're already using it with the absolute address of `word`, so you don't need `subiu` (which isn't a real machine instruction anyway, only addiu with a negative).  `sb $zero, word-2($a2)`.  Or better do a pointer increment so it can work without pseudo-instructions if `word` isn't in the low or high 32KiB of address-space.